# How to pass props to an imported component in styled-components

Tags: android, reactjs, typescript, react-native, styled-components

a challenge has arisen here, I'm using `React Native` and I need to pass props to `RectButton`, does anyone know how?

Because it is not a standard React Native feature, it is imported from `react-native-gesture-handler`, so I don't have access to it through `styled-components`, I would like something 'like this':

```
export const CheckBoxInput = styled(RectButton)<CheckBoxInputProps>`
  border: 1px solid ${h4_app_color};
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;

  ${(props) =>
    props.filled
      ? css`
          background-color: ${h4_app_color};
        `
      : css`
          background-color: white;
        `}
`;
```

My props are like this:

```
interface CheckBoxInputProps {
  filled?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: I know this doesnt answer your question, but you could simplify your code here to say `background-color: ${({ filled }) => filled ? h4_app_color : 'white'}` just to make it a little more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have a problem checking the `filled` prop here. Apply it to the component by:

```
<CheckBoxInputProps filled={yourValueHere} />


export const CheckBoxInput = styled(RectButton)<CheckBoxInputProps>`
  border: 1px solid ${h4_app_color};
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;

  ${(props) =>
    props.filled
      ? css`
          background-color: ${h4_app_color};
        `
      : css`
          background-color: white;
        `}
`;
```

If you specifically want to pass the prop along to the component `<RectButton />` without applying it to its style, then you could do this:

```
export const CheckBoxInput = styled(RectButton).attrs((
 {filledValue}: {filledValue: boolean}
) => {
 filled: filledValue   <-- This will pass the value to RectButtons 'filled' prop
}))<CheckBoxInputProps>`

`;
```

And use it like so:

```
<CheckBoxInputProps filledValue={yourValueHere} />
```